# Saving a bmp object into the highest quality possible

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, bitmap

I have a piece of code that create a heatmap, and everything is saved into a bitmap image. My main method is below.

```
        HeatMap map = new HeatMap(colors, width, height, file, U, V);
        _maps.Clear();
        _maps.Add(map);

        Bitmap newBMP = overlayBitmap(map.Image, width * 3, height * 3, times, dates, colors); // resizes the bmp without blending colors

        if (save) {
            newBMP.Save(file, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

---

`HeatMap()` is a method that takes in those parameters, creates a `bitmap`, and stores it into an instance.

`overlayBitmap()` is a method that takes my previously made map, through some `InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor` enlarges the images, and puts text onto this heatmap graph, like x/y-axis labels and title.

Then I use a simple `save` method.

My question is - what is the best way to save the `bmp` into the highest quality possible? I opted for `.png` instead of `.jpeg`, but are there additional things I can do?

Comment: Use `ImageFormat.Bmp`. The BMP format is uncompressed. The alternative is to pull out each pixel yourself and write it directly into a file.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead png is lossless compression though, meaning it's smaller than bmp and _still_ 100% perfect quality.

Comment: Oh geez its been 4 years since I made that comment @Nyerguds.. so I can't really tell you why I suggested BMP over PNG. I can't even fathom a guess other than it being a lazy comment and not an answer.

Comment: Fair enough, heh.

Answer (score 1):

.png is the optimal way of storing a bmp without loosing quality, it is more effective then just zipping a bmp. And not a single pixel is lost.